# HtmlUnit does not load entire page

Tags: amazon-cloudfront, htmlunit

I have checked that HtmlUnit does not load part of this page:

```
https://www.milanuncios.com/mis-anuncios/
```

When inspected with a browser, the section:

```
<div class="ma-LayoutBasicMainContent">
```

Has into a lot of contents. But when loaded by HtmlUnit it is empty!

I have tried various webClient switches, including

```
webClient.setAjaxController(new NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController());
webClient.getOptions().setDownloadImages(true);
webClient.getOptions().setCssEnabled(true);
webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webClient.setJavaScriptTimeout(10000);
```

But always with same result: The "ma-LayoutBasicMainContent" section is not loaded. This is the code I use:

```
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.*;

class MarnvHtmlUnitTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        WebClient webClient = null;

        try {

            final long javascriptTimeout = 10000;

            webClient = new WebClient();
            webClient.setAjaxController(new NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController());
            webClient.getOptions().setDownloadImages(true);
            webClient.getOptions().setCssEnabled(true);
            webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webClient.setJavaScriptTimeout(10000);

            String loginURL = "https://www.milanuncios.com/mis-anuncios/";
            System.out.println("Connecting to " + loginURL + " (" + webClient.getBrowserVersion() + ")");

            HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage(loginURL);
            System.out.print("    Waiting for Javascript to complete...");
            long millis = System.currentTimeMillis();
            webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(javascriptTimeout);                              
            System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - millis + " milliseconds");
            if (!page.asText().contains("gestiona tus anuncios")) {
                System.out.println("ERROR!");
                System.out.println(page.asXml());
                System.out.println("EXITING. " + webClient.getWebWindows().size());
                return;
            }

            System.out.println("OK");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            if (webClient != null)
                webClient.close();
        }
    }
}
```

In case of correct page loading, the page should contain the text "gestiona tus anuncios".
Note that the call to "waitForBackgroundJavaScript" returns inmediately, which for me it's strange... it normaly waits some seconds until the page is completely loaded. I am using HtmlUnit 2.36.0.

Comment: Have you tried using webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScriptStartingBefore(javascriptTimeout); instead of webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(javascriptTimeout);?

Comment: Yes, I have. No difference.

Comment: I m facing similar kind of issue. Did u manage to resolve it by chance? Any workaround? @Javier

Comment: Hi @VishalKharde, sorry by the delay... these have been strange months I had no time to my hobbie (programming). Yes, the issue continue, at least with the highly dinamic loading page I refer to (www.milanuncios.com), even with the most recent version (2.42.0). If you would have news about the solution or a work around, I would be very happy to hear about it.